# UITableView Returns EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Now the tableView loads but when I try to scroll down the table the app crashes. Heres my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"ince mal");
    NSLog(@"%f", i);

    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    // fill it with contents
    TFHppleElement * element = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString * tagContent = [element content];
    cell.textLabel.text = tagContent;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: You have to accept more answers to your questions

Answer (score 2):

You havent allocated **element** and you try to release it. thats the problem.

Remove `[element release]` from your code.

Any object with retain count 0 get released, then it will crash.

Set [NSZombieEnabled](http://www.markj.net/iphone-memory-debug-nszombie/) to check which object get released.

EDIT:

Remove this lines also,

```
if (i == indexPath.row) {
    return nil;
}

[tagContent release];
```

If you want an empty cell then return as,

```
if (i == indexPath.row) {
        return cell;  //Before adding any cell contents.
    }
```

Comment: I tried that and it kinda helped... Now it loads the tableView without any problems but when I try and scroll down the table I once again get the EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: that is what I was talking about (see the first part of my answer)

Comment: @max: fine i havent check your answer. here some network failure. thats y. cool

Comment: absolutely no problem. just wanted to point to another problem

Answer (score 0):

Never do this (that would lead you to another crash (assertion failure)):

```
if (i == indexPath.row) {
    return nil;
}
```

As for your crash:

```
[element release];
[tagContent release];
```

remove these lines

Comment: Ya I fixed those two things and it loads but now when I try scroll through the tableView the app crashes

Comment: well, i'm sure there is still a whole bunch of bugs in your code :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not seeing anything bad in these code. The content filling lines may cause some problem. I dont even find any release in your question. CellForRow gets fired whenever you tried to scroll. So check for the array, for accessing its object.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your TableView, only the way you use it. In the class you use it it is allocated, initialized and shown. But I bet you don't hold a pointer to it that keeps it from getting garbage collected.